# What callback can we use on search results

Tags: ruby-on-rails

What callback can we use on search results, which allows us to add few more transient attributes to the search results apart from the database record

https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `after_find` as it will be called after record loaded from database.

> The after_find callback will be called whenever Active Record loads a record from the database. after_find is called before after_initialize if both are defined.

https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html#after-initialize-and-after-find